# Проблема алгоритма бекапирования изображений

Tags: php, алгоритм, изображения, оптимизация

Есть код для работы с изображениями, целью которого является ,и сжатия изображений. Проблемы возникают в нехватке ресурсов. Скрип выполняется не до конца с ошибкой 504.

```
function backupimage($dir){
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $key) {
        $imageiofile = "/home/bitrix/ext_www/"
            . "host.svarbi.ru/upload/iblock/".$key."/*.*";
          foreach (glob($imageiofile) as $filename) {
           // echo basename($filename)."\n";
            $newfile = "/home/bitrix/ext_www/host.svarbi.ru/ttt/aaa/"
                    .$key."/".basename($filename);
            if (!copy($filename, $newfile)) {
                echo "не удалось скопировать $file...\n";
            }
        }
    }

}
backupimage($dir);
```

Нужно как то разбить это все на куски и проделать. Какой алгоритм для этого лучше использовать?

Comment: К сожалению 504 =(

Comment: Как при Dos атаке

Comment: Такие задачи нужно делать не через web сервера, а в консоли через ssh, например. У вас, скорее всего, не хватает таймаута.

Comment: Нет персонала для этого

Comment: Какой персонал? Скрипт по крону и все.

Comment: Это хорошо, но ни питона ни баша я толком не знаю. Там нужно написать скрипт, который будет копировать структуру папок и сжимать image magick c теми же именами и делать бек. Писем крон еще должен получать события от битрикса. Не спорю, лучше бы на python написал и на крон.

Comment: никто не мешает запустить выполнение пхп скрипта из командной строки `php   /path/to/my/script.php`. Либо в начало файла вписываете интепритатор (`#!/path/to/php`), и ставите права execute (`+x`) php-файлу, и просто прописываете его в крон. так что ни в баше ни в питоне необходимости нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот скрипт никогда не будет работать правильно. Для начала сделайте фильтрацию полученных значений scandir (исключить '.' '..' из результатов).
Вероятно, после этого все будет работать.